# Not able to maintain record type dependency when using apex:input field

Tags: visualforce, record-type

Has anyone tried this. Maintaining record type and field dependency using apex input field, it seems it does not work:

```
<apex:page standardController="Case">
   <apex:form >
       <apex:inputField value="{!Case.RecordTypeId}"></apex:inputField>
       <apex:inputField value="{!Case.TestField__c}"></apex:inputField>
   </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

for few record types testField__c has some values and other it has different values, but whenever I change the recordTypeId, the testField does not seems to change, it always shows same set of values according to default record type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The form needs to reload in order to detect the change in record type:

```
<apex:inputField value="{!Case.RecordTypeId}">
  <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" />
</apex:inputField>
```

Comment: Ok, the form reloads fully and the user will be able to see the reload. Is there a way to trigger this code via jquery or native js, so that user wint know if the page is reloading.

Comment: @NagendraSingh You can use apex:actionStatus to provide a reload message. Check the documentation for more information. You could also use native JS or jQuery + apex:actionFunction to rerender if you like. This answer only addressed the core issue about the need to refresh the form.

Comment: Yes, ok I figured, when I just pass the rendered output panel id, it just rerenders that output panel id and not the full page. Thanks